# Does Astyanax write use "default_time_to_live"?

Tags: java, cassandra, ttl, astyanax

I am writing data into a Cassandra cluster using Astyanax like so:

```
private void writeToBatch(Collection<Program> programBatch, MutationBatch batch) {
    ColumnFamily<UUID, String> programsCF = keyspaceProvider.getColumnFamily(PROGRAMS_COLUMN_FAMILY);
    programBatch.forEach(program -> {
        batch.withRow(programsCF, program.getProgramId())
                .putColumn(COLUMN_NAME_TITLE, program.getTitle())
                .putColumn(COLUMN_NAME_LANGUAGE, program.getLanguage().getShortCode())
                .putColumn(COLUMN_NAME_COUNTRY, program.getCountry().getCode())
                .putColumn(COLUMN_NAME_START, program.getStart())
                .putColumn(COLUMN_NAME_STOP, program.getStop())
                .putColumn(COLUMN_NAME_STREAM, program.getStream());
    });
}
...
batch.execute();
```

Table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE "RS"."Programs" (
    key uuid,
    column1 text,
    value blob,
    PRIMARY KEY (key, column1)
) WITH COMPACT STORAGE
    AND CLUSTERING ORDER BY (column1 ASC)
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 2592000
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = 'NONE';
```

Version: [cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.0.9 | CQL spec 3.4.0 | Native protocol v4]

The table that I write into has a `default_time_to_live` of 30 days, but the data that is being written in there seems to have TTL `null` and is never deleted. I was under the assumption that if I don't specify a TTL in the write, the default one of the table will be used?

Comment: We need additional info to be able to answer. Please update your original question with (1) the table schema, and (2) the Cassandra version. Cheers!